# Open a website with existing cookies ( C# Selenium )

Tags: c#, selenium, cookies

I tried to open Facebook with my existing cookies but it always return an exception

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:54255/session/c290a8ce809a0f20399bdd0b6f39dfcb/cookie. The status of the exception was KeepAliveFailure, and the message was: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.'

Here is my code:

```cs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
options.AddArguments("disable-gpu");
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string cookiestring = "fr=1EUiIsTbGFzBrDdNZ.AWV6jGoHMLx3jdI380Jt71UNs2Cs.BfyLv3.xw.AAA.0.0.BfyLv5.AWWnU2uMDHQ; xs=41%3AoxgS31SsWovyQg%3A2%31A1606990842%3A6501%3A6393; datr=97vIXydX2CbQrr4mqoyXmFv1N; c_user=100010294033451; spin=r.1003043930_b.trunk_t.1606990844_s.1_v.2_; wd=929x888; sb=9rvIXxOYyz7UfsZcKyZGOWbI; useragent=TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzg3LjAuNDI4MC44OCBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2; _uafec=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F87.0.4280.88%20Safari%2F537.36; ";
List<string> detail_cookie = cookiestring.Split(
new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None
).ToList();
chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://facebook.com");
foreach (string detail in detail_cookie)
{
    if (detail.Length < 2) continue;
    string key = detail.Substring(0, detail.IndexOf("="));
    string value = detail.Substring(detail.IndexOf("=") + 1);
    Cookie cookietemp = new Cookie(key, value);
    chromeDriver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookietemp);
}
```

Comment: You are using https (secure) which means a TLS authentication is used to make the connection.  The TLS authentication occurs before the request is sent.  The exceptions says no response was returned.  Normally when you send a request you will get back a 200 OK for a good response or a 400/500 error response.  You are not getting any response which is most likely due to the TLS authentication failing.  You have to use TLS 1.2/1.3. (1.0/1.1 is not long be used.  So try adding at beginning of code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: Im going to try that, tyvm!